# Total power of received signal under uniform scattering

Tags: calculus, integration, signal-processing

The PSD of the received signal $r(t)$, under uniform scattering, is given by:
$$ S_r(f) = \cases {
\frac{P_r}{2 \pi f_D} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (|f - f_c|/f_D)^2}} & \text{, if } |f - f_c| \leq f_D\cr
0 & \text{, otherwise }
}
$$
On every textbook I looked up (Wireless Communications by Andrea Goldsmith, p. 75 and a few others) it says that this PSD integrates to $P_r$, however, when I do the integration I always obtain $\infty$. My result seems to make sense as $S_r(f_c + f_D) = S_r(f_c - f_D) = \infty$.

My question is, how is it possible to obtain that the total power is equal to $P_r$ when the PSD integral goes to infinity?

Comment: You are doing something wrong in your calculation. Also, the fact the integrand tends to infinity at the integration limits does not necessarily mean that the integral is infinite.

Comment: Hi @Stelios, I'm doing integration by substitution, integrating over a new variable u = (f_c - f)/f_D when f <= f_c and u = (f - f_c)/f_D when f >= f_c. The result I get is arctanh(1) - arctanh(0) which is equal to infinity. Can you help me by shedding some light on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The result after the variable transformation is $\arcsin(1)-\arcsin(0)$

Comment: Thanks! I noticed I forgot the square root and switched the signals on my calculations.

Comment: PSD = Point Spread Distribution ? Always explain the abbreviations, acronyms, etc. you use.

Comment: Sorry, it actually means power spectral density.